# Signed binary representation in C

Tags: c, gcc

After reading [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html), binary constants can be written in place for binary in GCC like so:

```
int foo = 0b1010;
```

And expectantly prints out `10` with `printf("%d", foo)`.

However, with the keyword `signed` attached (despite `int` being signed by default), does not affect GCC's interpretation of 0b1010 (should be `-6`). Why is this so, and is it possible to make binary constants signed?

Comment: Why do you think the first digit after `b` is the sign bit for your 2s-compliment? Your int is probably 32 bits wide.

Comment: `0x8` is 8, not -8. `0b1` is 1, not -1. Why should `0b1010` be negative?

Comment: `0b1010` is `10` no matter how you slice it. In twos-compliment, you need to take the bitwise *not* and add `1` for storage as a negative value. In that case bit-31 (the sign bit) will be `1` (sign extended) with `1010` at the end. (e.g. `11111111111111111111111111111010`)  That is `-6` for a 4-byte integer in a twos-compliment system.

Comment: Binary constants are `int` values.  They are not treated as 4-bit (signed) quantities just because you only specified 4 bits.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Realizing `int` is 32-bit and the significance of the forward bit answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric constants have type `int` by default.  The constant `0b1010` is of this type as well.

Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes on your system, this is equivalent to writing `0b00000000000000000000000000001010`.  Assuming 2's compliment representation, the sign bit is not set so this is not a negative number.  Its value is 10 in decimal.

If you instead gave `0b11111111111111111111111111111010` as the value, it would be -6.